# AWS Load Balancer - Multiple vs single

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, performance-testing

Hello AWS practitioners,

We have a single classic load balancer for 8 EC2 instances, which makes more than a million request ever hour.

My queries are:

1. If we increase the number of load balancers from 1 to 2 or more, does that will improve the performance (significantly)?
2. We only make HTTPs requests, switching from Classic to ALB will improve the performance ?
3. What are the settings or attributes that we should be looking for optimising the performance and reduce the cost?

Comment: Please make one specific question, rather then asking multiple generic sub questions under one so question. As of now, your question lacks focus and details.

Comment: I mostly agree with @Marcin, I don't feel you already did alot of research yourself into your specific problem. Hope my answer helps you go into the right direction but with such a broad question there can never be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. it should not significantly improve performance as a loadbalancer only distributes load over these 8 instances.
2. This could improve performance if you can benefit of the features of the new version of ALB
3. reducing costs and optimizing performance are most of the time counter opposites.

- If you want to reduce costs you can look at using smaller instance sizes
  (less memory/cpus).
- If you want to improve performance you should
  look at instance types  but most of the time the biggest boost is
  found in optimizing database calls / caching / queueing tasks which can also be handled asynchronously. (for ex. most applications start with sending e-mails/notifications synchronously. By doing this async, as in pushing these messages to a queue, can significantly improve performance.)

General suggestion: use application profiling tools (New Relic/Datadog/Kibana's apm app) or load testing tools (for ex. Apache JMeter) on your application to simulate, benchmark and test your specific application on different instance types / sizes to get a better view where your specific bottlenecks are.